# React Native - Use pre-populated database file file local storage on phone

Tags: react-native, sqlite

am using https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage

and i have to use pre populated db file from user's local storage which user download from our server,
i use

```js
SQLite.openDatabase({name : "testDB", createFromLocation: "/sdcard/test boat/dd. sqlite"}, callback, errorCallback);
```

i get error unable to open database, can any one help me to get out